# event.preventDefault() is not working

Tags: jquery, e-commerce, preventdefault

I'm trying to delete an item from my items on cart in an ecommerce website, im using jquery for that matter  but nothing works...
my link that i click on to lunch the jquery:

```
<a class="btn addpanier" href="addpanier.php?id=<?php echo $a['id'];?>">
```

my jquery code :

```
(function($){

$('.removepanier').click(function(event){ 
event.preventDefault();

$.get($(this).attr('href'),{},function(data){
    if (data.error) {
        alert(data.message);
    }else{
        if(confirm(data.message + '. Voulez vous revenir en accueil?')){
            location.href="index.php";
        }else{
            $('#panier12').empty().append(data.panier);
            $('#total12').empty().append(data.total1 + ' MAD');
            $('#total2').empty().append(data.total1 + ' MAD');
            $('#panier2').empty().append(data.panier);

        }
    }
},'json');
return false;
});
})(jQuery);
```

the code is working correctly but it takes me to the link written in href, which is not what i want...

Comment: There is no element with the `removepanier` class.

Comment: i don't get you... what do you mean ?

Comment: How can you tell code is working if you leave the page? Doesn't make sense. Note that `(function($){` is not the same as using `$(function()` or `$(document).ready()`

Comment: it is working because it displays it on removepanier.php, and when i go back to my page i find it correctly displayed, all i want is to directly display it without heading to removepanier.php...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(
$('.removepanier').click(function(event){ 
event.preventDefault();

$.get($(this).attr('url'),{},function(data){
    if (data.error) {
        alert(data.message);
    }else{
        if(confirm(data.message + '. Voulez vous revenir en accueil?')){
            location.href="index.php";
        }else{
            $('#panier12').empty().append(data.panier);
            $('#total12').empty().append(data.total1 + ' MAD');
            $('#total2').empty().append(data.total1 + ' MAD');
            $('#panier2').empty().append(data.panier);

        }
    }
},'json');
return false;
});
)
```

change your href `attr` with `url` in your html

Comment: still it is not working... how can i make it work ? (if i should modify the markup <a>  i can do it...) but what to do  next ?

Comment: i forget you have to add `$(document).ready(function(){ code here });`